# Using same x:Name in usercontrols with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I use MVVM Light in my WPF-application.
I have some usercontrol. It passes element by elementname as commandparameter to command.

```
<UserControl>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"     CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Image}"></cmd:EventToCommand>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<image Name="Image" />
</UserControl>
```

In my MainView I use this usercontrols:

```
<Window>
  <l:mycontrol />
  <l:mycontrol />
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
 class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
 {
    public MainViewModel()
    {
       LoadCommand = new RelayCommand<Image>(OnLoad);
    }

    private void OnLoad(Image image)
    {
       Draw(image,bitmap);
    }
 }
```

"Draw" is my function for writing on Image with some usercontrol's parameters.
Cause Images have the same x:name, my application draws only on the last image.
How else I can pass my element to command?

Comment: Have you tried simply giving your controls different `x:Name` attributes in the Window element?

Comment: Changing the Name is the easiest way forward if you have a fixed number of UserControls. You want to be a wee bit cautious about dealing with controls like that - you're breaking the MVVM pattern by handling interface elements and drawing methods in your ViewModel. When I've done this before, I've used the Messenger class to send a 'DoSomething' message from the VM to the View codebehind. Receiving the message triggers a codebehind method that executes your UI changes. This maintains a separation between your business logic and UI.